# conda update InvalidSpecError

Tags: conda

I am trying to update a conda environment:

```
conda update --all
```

but get the following

```
Fetching package metadata .............

InvalidSpecError: Invalid spec: =20190808
```

output of `conda list` is as follows:

```
 alabaster                 0.7.10           py36h174008c_0  
 anaconda                  custom           py36ha4fed55_0  
 anaconda-client           1.6.14                   py36_0  
 anaconda-navigator        1.6.4                    py36_0  
 anaconda-project          0.8.2            py36h9ee5d53_0  
 apipkg                    1.5                       <pip>
 appnope                   0.1.0            py36hf537a9a_0  
 appnope                   0.1.0                     <pip>
 appscript                 1.0.1            py36h9e71e49_1  
 arrow-cpp                 0.8.0                    py36_4    conda-forge
 asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py36_0  
 astroid                   1.6.3                    py36_0  
 astropy                   3.0.2            py36h917ab60_1  
 attrs                     18.1.0                   py36_0  
 babel                     2.5.3                    py36_0  
 backcall                  0.1.0                     <pip>
 backcall                  0.1.0                    py36_0  
 backports                 1.0              py36ha3c1827_1  
 backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0            py36hd7a2ee4_2  
 bash_kernel               0.7.1                     <pip>
 bctpy                     0.5.0                     <pip>
 beautifulsoup4            4.6.0            py36h72d3c9f_1  
 billiard                  3.5.0.4                   <pip>
 biopython                 1.72             py36h6440ff4_0    anaconda
 bitarray                  0.8.1            py36h1de35cc_1  
 bkcharts                  0.2              py36h073222e_0  
 blas                      1.0                         mkl  
 blaze                     0.11.3           py36h02e7a37_0  
 bleach                    2.1.3                    py36_0  
 bleach                    2.1.3                     <pip>
 blosc                     1.14.3               hd9629dc_0  
 bokeh                     0.12.16                  py36_0  
 boto                      2.48.0           py36hdbc59ac_1  
 bottleneck                1.2.1            py36hbd380ad_0  
 brainnetworks             0.3.2                     <pip>
 bz2file                   0.98                       py_0    conda-forge
 bzip2                     1.0.6                h1de35cc_5  
 ca-certificates           2018.03.07                    0  
 cairo                     1.14.12              he60d9cb_2  
 certifi                   2018.4.16                py36_0  
 cffi                      1.11.5           py36h342bebf_0  
 cffi                      1.13.2                    <pip>
 chardet                   3.0.4            py36h96c241c_1  
 click                     6.7              py36hec950be_0  
 click-plugins             1.0.3                     <pip>
 cligj                     0.4.0                     <pip>
 cloog                     0.18.0                        0  
 cloudpickle               0.5.3                    py36_0  
 clyent                    1.2.2            py36hae3ad88_0  
 colorama                  0.3.9            py36hd29a30c_0  
 configparser              3.5.0                     <pip>
 connectome-builder        1.21                      <pip>
 contextlib2               0.5.5            py36hd66e5e7_0  
 cryptography              2.2.2            py36h1de35cc_0  
 curl                      7.60.0               ha441bb4_0  
 cvxopt                    1.2.0            py36hb579ef3_0  
 cycler                    0.10.0           py36hfc81398_0  
 cython                    0.28.2           py36h1de35cc_0  
 cytoolz                   0.9.0.1          py36h1de35cc_0  
 dask                      0.17.5                   py36_0  
 dask-core                 0.17.5                   py36_0  
 datashape                 0.5.4            py36hfb22df8_0  
 dbus                      1.13.2               h760590f_1  
 decorator                 4.3.0                     <pip>
 decorator                 4.3.0                    py36_0  
 descartes                 1.1.0                     <pip>
 dipy                      0.15.0           py36h7eb728f_0    conda-forge
 distributed               1.21.8                   py36_0  
 docutils                  0.14             py36hbfde631_0  
 entropy-estimators        1.0                       <pip>
 entrypoints               0.2.3            py36hd81d71f_2  
 entrypoints               0.2.3                     <pip>
 et_xmlfile                1.0.1            py36h1315bdc_0  
 execnet                   1.5.0                     <pip>
 expat                     2.2.5                hb8e80ba_0  
 fastcache                 1.0.2            py36h1de35cc_2  
 fasteners                 0.14.1                    <pip>
 feather-format            0.4.0                    py36_2    conda-forge
 feather-format            0.4.0                     <pip>
 ffmpeg                    4.0                  hc84425e_0  
 filelock                  3.0.4                    py36_0  
 Fiona                     1.7.13                    <pip>
 flake8                    3.5.0                    py36_1  
 flask                     1.0.2                    py36_1  
 flask-cors                3.0.4                    py36_0  
 fontconfig                2.12.6               h9850fc5_0  
 freetype                  2.8                  h12048fb_1  
 funcsigs                  1.0.2                     <pip>
 future                    0.16.0                    <pip>
 future                    0.17.1                   py36_0  
 futures                   3.1.1                     <pip>
 gast                      0.2.2                     <pip>
 gcc                       4.8.5                         8  
 geopandas                 0.4.0                     <pip>
 get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h7520d66_0  
 gettext                   0.19.8.1             h15daf44_3  
 gevent                    1.3.0            py36h1de35cc_0  
 glib                      2.56.1               h35bc53a_0  
 glob2                     0.6              py36h94c9186_0  
 glpk                      4.65              h0a95893_1001    conda-forge
 gmp                       6.1.2                hb37e062_1  
 gmpy2                     2.0.8            py36hf9c35bd_2  
 gnutls                    3.5.17                        0    conda-forge
 greenlet                  0.4.13           py36h1de35cc_0  
 gsl                       2.4                  h1de35cc_4  
 h5py                      2.8.0            py36h967a92a_0  
 hdf5                      1.8.18               h017327d_1  
 heapdict                  1.0.0                    py36_2  
 hide-code                 0.5.2                     <pip>
 html5lib                  1.0.1                     <pip>
 html5lib                  1.0.1            py36h2f9c1c0_0  
 icu                       58.2                 h4b95b61_1  
 idna                      2.6              py36h8628d0a_1  
 igraph                    0.7.1             h0a67f88_1005    conda-forge
 imageio                   2.3.0                    py36_0  
 imagesize                 1.0.0                    py36_0  
 infomap                   1.0.0b8                   <pip>
 intel-openmp              2018.0.0                      8  
 ipykernel                 4.8.2                    py36_0  
 ipykernel                 4.8.2                     <pip>
 ipython                   6.5.0                     <pip>
 ipython                   6.4.0                    py36_0  
 ipython-genutils          0.2.0                     <pip>
 ipython_genutils          0.2.0            py36h241746c_0  
 ipywidgets                7.2.1                     <pip>
 ipywidgets                7.2.1                    py36_0  
 isl                       0.12.2                        1  
 isodate                   0.6.0                     <pip>
 isort                     4.3.4                    py36_0  
 itsdangerous              0.24             py36h49fbb8d_1  
 jbig                      2.1                  h4d881f8_0  
 jdcal                     1.4                      py36_0  
 jedi                      0.12.0                    <pip>
 jedi                      0.12.0                   py36_1  
 jinja2                    2.10             py36hd36f9c5_0  
 Jinja2                    2.10                      <pip>
 jpeg                      9b                   he5867d9_2  
 jsoncpp                   1.8.4                h04f5b5a_0  
 jsonschema                2.6.0                     <pip>
 jsonschema                2.6.0            py36hb385e00_0  
 jupyter                   1.0.0                    py36_4  
 jupyter                   1.0.0                     <pip>
 jupyter-client            5.2.3                     <pip>
 jupyter-console           5.2.0                     <pip>
 jupyter-core              4.4.0                     <pip>
 jupyter_client            5.2.3                    py36_0  
 jupyter_console           5.2.0            py36hccf5b1c_1  
 jupyter_core              4.4.0            py36h79cf704_0  
 jupyterlab                0.32.1                   py36_0  
 jupyterlab_launcher       0.10.5                   py36_0  
 Keras                     2.3.1                     <pip>
 Keras-Applications        1.0.8                     <pip>
 Keras-Preprocessing       1.1.0                     <pip>
 kiwisolver                1.0.1            py36h792292d_0  
 lazy-object-proxy         1.3.1            py36h2fbbe47_0  
 libcurl                   7.60.0               hf30b1f0_0  
 libcxx                    4.0.1                h579ed51_0  
 libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hebd6815_0  
 libedit                   3.1.20170329         hb402a30_2  
 libffi                    3.2.1                h475c297_4  
 libgfortran               3.0.1                h93005f0_2  
 libiconv                  1.15                 hdd342a3_7  
 libidn11                  1.33                          0    conda-forge
 libopus                   1.2.1                h169cedb_0  
 libpng                    1.6.34               he12f830_0  
 libsodium                 1.0.16               h3efe00b_0  
 libssh2                   1.8.0                h322a93b_4  
 libtiff                   4.0.9                hcb84e12_1  
 libvpx                    1.7.0                h378b8a2_0  
 libxml2                   2.9.8                hab757c2_1  
 libxslt                   1.1.32               hb819dd2_0  
 line-profiler             2.1.2                     <pip>
 llvmlite                  0.23.1           py36hc454e04_0  
 locket                    0.2.0            py36hca03003_1  
 lxml                      4.2.1            py36h7166777_0  
 lzo                       2.10                 h362108e_2  
 Markdown                  2.6.11                    <pip>
 MarkupSafe                1.0                       <pip>
 markupsafe                1.0              py36h3a1e703_1  
 matplotlib                2.2.3                     <pip>
 matplotlib                2.2.2            py36ha7267d0_0  
 mccabe                    0.6.1            py36hdaeb55d_0  
 metakernel                0.20.14                    py_0    conda-forge
 metis                     5.1.0             h0a44026_1003    conda-forge
 mistune                   0.8.3            py36h1de35cc_1  
 mistune                   0.8.3                     <pip>
 mizani                    0.4.6                     <pip>
 mkl                       2018.0.3                      1  
 mkl-service               1.1.2            py36h7ea6df4_4  
 mkl_fft                   1.0.1            py36h917ab60_0  
 mkl_random                1.0.1            py36h78cc56f_0  
 mock                      2.0.0                     <pip>
 monotonic                 1.5                       <pip>
 more-itertools            4.1.0                    py36_0  
 mpc                       1.0.3                h7a72875_5  
 mpfr                      3.1.5                h711e7fd_2  
 mpmath                    1.0.0            py36hf1b8295_2  
 msgpack                   1.0.0                     <pip>
 msgpack-python            0.5.6            py36h04f5b5a_0  
 multipledispatch          0.5.0                    py36_0  
 munch                     2.3.2                     <pip>
 navigator-updater         0.1.0                    py36_0  
 nbconvert                 5.3.1            py36h810822e_0  
 nbconvert                 5.3.1                     <pip>
 nbformat                  4.4.0                     <pip>
 nbformat                  4.4.0            py36h827af21_0  
 ncurses                   6.1                  h0a44026_0  
 nettle                    3.3                           0    conda-forge
 networkx                  2.1                      py36_0  
 neurdflib                 5.0.0.post1               <pip>
 nibabel                   2.3.3                      py_0    conda-forge
 nibabel                   2.3.0                     <pip>
 nilearn                   0.4.1                     <pip>
 nilearn                   0.5.0              pyh24bf2e0_0    conda-forge
 nipy                      0.4.2                     <pip>
 nipy                      0.4.1           py36h917ab60_1001    conda-forge
 nipype                    1.1.9.dev0                <pip>
 nltk                      3.3.0                    py36_0  
 nose                      1.3.7            py36h73fae2b_2  
 notebook                  5.5.0                    py36_0  
 notebook                  5.6.0                     <pip>
 numba                     0.38.0           py36h1702cab_0  
 numexpr                   2.6.5            py36h057f876_0  
 numpy                     1.14.3           py36h9bb19eb_1  
 numpy                     1.16.2                    <pip>
 numpy-base                1.14.3           py36h479e554_1  
 numpydoc                  0.8.0                    py36_0  
 oct2py                    4.0.6                      py_1    conda-forge
 octave_kernel             0.28.4                     py_1    conda-forge
 odo                       0.5.1            py36hc1af34a_0  
 olefile                   0.45.1                   py36_0  
 openpyxl                  2.5.3                    py36_0  
 openssl                   1.0.2o               h26aff7b_0  
 packaging                 17.1                     py36_0  
 palettable                3.1.1                     <pip>
 pandas                    0.23.0           py36h1702cab_0  
 pandas                    0.23.4                    <pip>
 pandoc                    1.19.2.1             ha5e8f32_1  
 pandocfilters             1.4.2                     <pip>
 pandocfilters             1.4.2            py36h3b0b094_1  
 parquet-cpp               1.4.0.pre                     2    conda-forge
 parso                     0.2.0                    py36_0  
 parso                     0.2.0                     <pip>
 partd                     0.3.8            py36hf5c4cb8_0  
 path.py                   11.0.1                   py36_0  
 pathlib2                  2.3.2                    py36_0  
 patsy                     0.5.0                    py36_0  
 pbr                       4.2.0                     <pip>
 pcre                      8.42                 h378b8a2_0  
 pdfkit                    0.6.1                     <pip>
 pep8                      1.7.1                    py36_0  
 pexpect                   4.5.0                     <pip>
 pexpect                   4.5.0                    py36_0  
 pfile-tools               0.3.2                     <pip>
 pickleshare               0.7.4            py36hf512f8e_0  
 pickleshare               0.7.4                     <pip>
 pillow                    5.1.0            py36hfcce615_0  
 pip                       18.0                      <pip>
 pip                       10.0.1                   py36_0  
 pixman                    0.34.0            h1de35cc_1003    conda-forge
 pkginfo                   1.4.2                    py36_1  
 plotnine                  0.4.0                     <pip>
 pluggy                    0.6.0            py36hb1d0581_0  
 ply                       3.11                     py36_0  
 prometheus-client         0.3.1                     <pip>
 prompt-toolkit            1.0.15                    <pip>
 prompt_toolkit            1.0.15           py36haeda067_0  
 prov                      1.5.3                     <pip>
 psutil                    5.4.5            py36h1de35cc_0  
 ptitprince                0.1.5                     <pip>
 ptyprocess                0.5.2                     <pip>
 ptyprocess                0.5.2            py36he6521c3_0  
 py                        1.5.3                    py36_0  
 pyarrow                   0.9.0.post1               <pip>
 pyarrow                   0.8.0                    py36_0    conda-forge
 pycairo                   1.18.0          py36ha54c0a8_1000    conda-forge
 pycodestyle               2.3.1            py36h83e8646_0  
 pycodestyle_magic         0.1                       <pip>
 pycosat                   0.6.3            py36hee92d8f_0  
 pycparser                 2.18             py36h724b2fc_1  
 pycrypto                  2.6.1            py36h1de35cc_8  
 pycurl                    7.43.0.1         py36hdbc3d79_0  
 pydicom                   1.2.2                      py_0    conda-forge
 pydicom                   1.1.0                     <pip>
 pydot                     1.2.4                     <pip>
 pydotplus                 2.0.2                     <pip>
 pyevtk                    1.1.0                     <pip>
 pyflakes                  1.6.0            py36hea45e83_0  
 pygments                  2.2.0            py36h240cd3f_0  
 Pygments                  2.2.0                     <pip>
 PyHamcrest                1.9.0                     <pip>
 pylint                    1.8.4                    py36_0  
 pyodbc                    4.0.23           py36h0a44026_0  
 pyopenssl                 18.0.0                   py36_0  
 pyparsing                 2.2.0            py36hb281f35_0  
 pyproj                    1.9.5.1                   <pip>
 pyqt                      5.9.2            py36h11d3b92_0  
 pysocks                   1.6.8                    py36_0  
 pytables                  3.4.4            py36hca30cd5_0  
 pytest                    3.5.1                    py36_0  
 pytest-arraydiff          0.2                      py36_0  
 pytest-astropy            0.3.0                    py36_0  
 pytest-doctestplus        0.1.3                    py36_0  
 pytest-forked             0.2                       <pip>
 pytest-openfiles          0.3.0                    py36_0  
 pytest-remotedata         0.2.1                    py36_0  
 pytest-xdist              1.22.5                    <pip>
 python                    3.6.5                hc167b69_1  
 python-dateutil           2.7.2                     <pip>
 python-dateutil           2.7.3                    py36_0  
 python-igraph             0.7.1.post6     py36h1de35cc_1005    conda-forge
 python-louvain            0.13                      <pip>
 python.app                2                        py36_8  
 pytz                      2018.4                   py36_0  
 pywavelets                0.5.2            py36h2710a04_0  
 pyyaml                    3.12             py36h2ba1e63_1  
 pyzmq                     17.0.0                    <pip>
 pyzmq                     17.0.0           py36h1de35cc_1  
 qt                        5.9.5                h02808f3_0  
 qtawesome                 0.4.4            py36h468c6fb_0  
 qtconsole                 4.3.1            py36hd96c0ff_0  
 qtconsole                 4.3.1                     <pip>
 qtpy                      1.4.1                    py36_0  
 rdflib                    4.2.2                     <pip>
 readline                  7.0                  hc1231fa_4  
 redis                     2.10.6                    <pip>
 requests                  2.18.4           py36h4516966_1  
 rope                      0.10.7           py36h68959ac_0  
 rpy2                      3.2.2                     <pip>
 rq                        0.12.0                    <pip>
 ruamel_yaml               0.15.35          py36h1de35cc_1  
 sas7bdat                  2.1.1                     <pip>
 saspy                     2.2.6                     <pip>
 scikit-image              0.13.1           py36h1de35cc_1  
 scikit-learn              0.19.1           py36hffbff8c_0  
 scipy                     1.4.1                     <pip>
 scipy                     1.1.0            py36hcaad992_0  
 scipy                     1.0.1                     <pip>
 seaborn                   0.9.0                    py36_0  
 send2trash                1.5.0                    py36_0  
 Send2Trash                1.5.0                     <pip>
 setuptools                39.1.0                    <pip>
 setuptools                39.1.0                   py36_0  
 Shapely                   1.6.4.post2               <pip>
 simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py36_2  
 simplegeneric             0.8.1                     <pip>
 SimpleITK                 1.2.0                     <pip>
 simplejson                3.16.0                    <pip>
 singledispatch            3.4.0.3          py36hf20db9d_0  
 sip                       4.19.8           py36h0a44026_0  
 six                       1.11.0                    <pip>
 six                       1.11.0           py36h0e22d5e_1  
 snappy                    1.1.7                he62c110_3  
 snowballstemmer           1.2.1            py36h6c7b616_0  
 sortedcollections         0.6.1                    py36_0  
 sortedcontainers          1.5.10                   py36_0  
 sos                       0.9.16.1                  <pip>
 sos-bash                  0.9.12.2                  <pip>
 sos-bioinfo               0.9.10.1                  <pip>
 sos-javascript            0.9.12.2                  <pip>
 sos-julia                 0.9.12.1                  <pip>
 sos-matlab                0.9.12.1                  <pip>
 sos-notebook              0.9.16.0                  <pip>
 sos-pbs                   0.9.16.0                  <pip>
 sos-python                0.9.12.1                  <pip>
 sos-r                     0.9.12.3                  <pip>
 sos-rq                    0.9.16.1                  <pip>
 sos-ruby                  0.9.15.0                  <pip>
 sos-sas                   0.9.12.3                  <pip>
 sphinx                    1.7.4                    py36_0  
 sphinxcontrib             1.0              py36h9364dc8_1  
 sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.0.1            py36h92f4a7a_1  
 spyder                    3.2.8                    py36_0  
 sqlalchemy                1.2.7            py36hb402a30_0  
 sqlite                    3.23.1               hf1716c9_0  
 statsmodels               0.9.0            py36h1d22016_0  
 suitesparse               5.2.0                he235d88_0  
 sympy                     1.1.1            py36h7f3cf04_0  
 tableone                  0.5.13                    <pip>
 tabulate                  0.8.2                     <pip>
 tbb                       2018_20171205                 0    conda-forge
 tblib                     1.3.2            py36hda67792_0  
 tensorflow-estimator      2.1.0                     <pip>
 termcolor                 1.1.0                     <pip>
 terminado                 0.8.1                     <pip>
 terminado                 0.8.1                    py36_1  
 testpath                  0.3.1                     <pip>
 testpath                  0.3.1            py36h625a49b_0  
 tk                        8.6.7                h35a86e2_3  
 toolz                     0.9.0                    py36_0  
 tornado                   5.0.2                    py36_0  
 tornado                   5.0.2                     <pip>
 tqdm                      4.24.0                    <pip>
 traitlets                 4.3.2            py36h65bd3ce_0  
 traitlets                 4.3.2                     <pip>
 traits                    4.6.0                     <pip>
 typing                    3.6.4                    py36_0  
 tzlocal                   2.0.0                     <pip>
 unicodecsv                0.14.1           py36he531d66_0  
 unixodbc                  2.3.6                h3efe00b_0  
 urllib3                   1.22             py36h68b9469_0  
 vtk                       8.1.0           py36h04d9db9_201  
 Wand                      0.4.4                     <pip>
 wcwidth                   0.1.7            py36h8c6ec74_0  
 wcwidth                   0.1.7                     <pip>
 webencodings              0.5.1            py36h3b9701d_1  
 webencodings              0.5.1                     <pip>
 werkzeug                  0.14.1                   py36_0  
 wheel                     0.31.1                   py36_0  
 widgetsnbextension        3.2.1                    py36_0  
 widgetsnbextension        3.2.1                     <pip>
 wrapt                     1.10.11          py36hc29e774_0  
 x264                      20131217                      3    conda-forge
 xlrd                      1.2.0                      py_0    conda-forge
 xlsxwriter                1.0.4                    py36_0  
 xlwings                   0.11.8                   py36_0  
 xlwt                      1.2.0            py36h5ad1178_0  
 xxhash                    1.2.0                     <pip>
 xz                        5.2.4                h1de35cc_4  
 yaml                      0.1.7                hc338f04_2  
 zeromq                    4.2.5                h378b8a2_0  
 zict                      0.1.3            py36h71da714_0  
 zlib                      1.2.11               hf3cbc9b_2
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of `conda list` in the question? Thank you!

Comment: It looks like a bunch of packages were installed with pip, is that correct? Also, why do most of the packages not have a channel listed?

Comment: Yes, the pip installs are troubling and may be causing some of the errors. What version of conda do you have? @AMC if the channel isn't listed, it is most likely `defaults`.

Comment: @darthbith _if the channel isn't listed, it is most likely `defaults`._ Yes, good point, the combination of different channels is likely contributing to the problems.

Comment: Any progress on this issue, @robmcc

Comment: I've had a multi-channel build going for years. I started hitting this exception in March 2020. I had change nothing; all packages are set to specific version. @AMC

Comment: There is an open issue on their GitHub that needs attention... https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/3915 @darthbith

Comment: @Sqandr I'm not an employee of Anaconda Inc., and I'm not sure how to help here.

Answer (score 1):

While not a solution, we came up with a workaround, so I figured I'd post it here.

Installing a newer version of conda in an alternative location, and using this specific activate binary to activate the environment allows installs to be functional once again.

Comment: This seems like a good start. Were you ultimately able to update the original `conda` in **base** so that the workaround was only temporary?

Answer (score 0):

While not a solution, this may lead someone else to a fix.  I ran into the same error and was able to get `conda update --all` to work again by removing pyarrow and a number of its C++ dependencies:

```
conda remove pyarrow arrow-cpp grpc-cpp parquet-cpp
```

There is a version of pyarrow on both the conda-forge and default channels, and something isn't resolving on older conda builds.

Once pyarrow is removed, you will get the same invalid specification error (above) if you attempt to reinstall the latest version of it and if you install an older version you will get the same error if you try `conda update --all` afterward.

Unfortunately, many packages are dependent on pyarrow, so removing it may not be a good option.  I pip installed pyarrow so I can use feather format with pandas, but I can no longer conda install any package that has a dependency on pyarrow.