# Geopandas install problem: InvalidSpecError

Tags: python, conda, geopandas

I'd created a new environment and wanted to install geopandas and its dependencies. However, I get the following error message when I do this:

```
(C:\Program Files\Anaconda3) C:\WINDOWS\system32>activate py37_SWS

(py37_SWS) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda install geopandas
Fetching package metadata ...............
Solving package specifications:

InvalidSpecError: Invalid spec: =20190808
```

Comment: Does it happen with geopandas only or with any other package as well?

Comment: What's the Conda version? (add output of `conda info` to question) Same error suggests outdated Conda: https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/3915. Are you using package pinning? Also seems it can bubble a similar error: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2212

Comment: Does this answer your question? [conda update InvalidSpecError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60757142/conda-update-invalidspecerror)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issue. Created a new python 3.7 environment and installed all geopandas dependencies and geopandas from pip wheels. Followed this tutorial: https://www.hatarilabs.com/ih-en/how-to-install-python-geopandas-on-anaconda-in-windows-tutorial